# Top down 2d 4 directional ai

Tags: unity-game-engine, artificial-intelligence

Hi im trying to create an ai for my game using unity and csharp
i am not sure how to go about it i want the ai to move in 4 directions so if player is diagonal from it it will go down then left ect

this is what ive tried but it only moves when i move and it dosent turn left or right

```
void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D other) 
{
    if (other.CompareTag("Player"))
    {
        if (transform.position.y < other.gameObject.transform.position.y)
        {
            rigidbody2D.transform.position += Vector3.up * speed * Time.deltaTime;
            anim.SetBool ("Backwards", true);
        }
        if (transform.position.y > other.gameObject.transform.position.y)
        {
            rigidbody2D.transform.position += Vector3.down * speed * Time.deltaTime;
            anim.SetBool ("Front", true);
        }


        if (transform.position.x > other.gameObject.transform.position.x)
        {
            rigidbody2D.transform.position += Vector3.left * speed * Time.deltaTime;
            anim.SetBool ("Left", true);
        }
        if (transform.position.x > other.gameObject.transform.position.x)
        {
            rigidbody2D.transform.position += Vector3.right * speed * Time.deltaTime;
            anim.SetBool ("RIght", true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should check out some basic tutorials first. Search google because there are a bunch of great tutorials to learn the basics from.

Comment: ive already goggled it for a few fays before asking the question all i really need to know if how do i get the ai to know to move down to the players z and then along to his x but i dont know how to do the logic

Comment: Just control one axis at a time. Check to see if the players x position is less than or greater than the enemy position x then move it. Don't go on to the z axis until your x axis is at the correct point.

Comment: ok that does make sense ill see if i can try that and il ask if i need help

Comment: ive added above what ive tried but ti does not work